# How to fetch id when using dup.update_attributes()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
p = product.dup.update_attributes(name: "The latest thing")
```

The code above creates (and saves) a duplicate of the `product` object, with one attribute altered.

**How do I retrieve the id of the newly created record? The variable `p` is only returning `true`.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that p is equal to what return update_attributes ( true if the update was successfull, false if not)

You should do this:

```
product_copy = product.dup # copies the product into a new one, stocked in variable product_copy
product_copy.update_attributes(name: "The latest thing")
product_copy # => your Product object
```

An alternative:

```
product_copy = product.dup
product_copy.name = "The latest thing"
product_copy.save
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns `true` because `update_attributes` is the last method that gets evaluated. So `p` gets assigned the value of the `update_attributes` method, which will either be `true` or `false`.

```
p = product.dup
p.update_attributes(name: "The latest thing")
p.id
```